# Regex analyser for PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I would like to be able to inspect the structure of a PCRE regex. Is there a way to do this in PHP? Is there an internal function, or an extra extension, or even just a 3rd party class? Or will I have to write my own analyser, and if so, are there any caveats I should bear in mind?

Edit: Many people have pointed out that PHP's pcre exposes no functionality for this, and nobody has been able to suggest a PHP library that has been written for this task. I'm happy to consider hare-brained solutions involving piping the output of analysers from other languages into PHP, or something crazier.

Comment: What do you mean inspect the structure? The regex pattern IS the structure.

Comment: No internal PHP functions, as libpcre doesn't expose much. I'm also unaware of any regex parser in PHP, and most online tools will probably use Perl and one of the helpful CPAN modules in that area. Only one caveat I can think of: it's going to be difficult.

Comment: Please don't try to accomplish this with regular expressions. Please.

Comment: Wouldn't dream of it, meagar.

Comment: @mario, could you please add an answer that describes what can be done to analyse the expressions in Perl? I suppose if I was desperate I could emit the result from Perl as JSON. It would be a bit hacky, but it could get the job done.

Comment: @Tyler, Just as PHP code *is* the structure? Making something like [this](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php) have no earthly use?

Comment: @Shabbyrobe: Perl solution, but is this what you are trying to do? http://perladvent.pm.org/2010/1/

Comment: @Hugmeir, kinda. But I'd like to get whatever structure it's using to generate that pseudo-comment stuff, rather than something that has already been formatted like that.

Comment: I guess taking a stab at the source is out of the question? http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/GSULLIVAN/YAPE-Regex-Explain-4.01/Explain.pm

Comment: @Hugmier - thanks for the link, but I'm not sure what I'm looking at there. I don't really know any Perl, I was just suggesting it as a loopy idea for getting it done. Can you have a stab at an answer that pulls those ideas together into something I can call from PHP (system() is OK)? It's certainly worth a +1 even if it doesn't fully work out for me :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way you can do this in PHP. If you're looking for a regex analyzer, I find Regex Buddy (http://www.regexbuddy.com/) very useful. It's not free, but is relatively inexpensive. I'm not connected in any way - just a satisfied user.

Comment: It's not for me to inspect my own pattern for debugging, it's for me to write code that makes decisions based on the characteristics of a regex pattern.